# RethinkDB pagination using slice or limit & skip with changes()

Tags: pagination, rethinkdb

How can i do pagination in RethinkDB with changes()?

None of these options does not work:

```
r.db('bustest').table('client').orderBy({index: r.desc("id")}).slice(3, 3).changes()

r.db('bustest').table('client').orderBy({index: r.desc("id")}).skip(3).limit(3).changes()
```

Only it works:

```
r.db('bustest').table('client').orderBy({index: r.desc("id")}).limit(3).changes()
```

UPDATE:

For example, skip after changes():

```
r.db('bustest').table('client').orderBy({index: r.desc("id")}).limit(3).changes({squash: 0.05, includeInitial: true, includeStates: true})
```

return:

```
{
"state":  "ready"
},
{
"new_val": {
"first_name":  "Gruzin" ,
"id":  "e9580339-b908-4349-a208-c3d1e25bf7ba" ,
"last_name":  "Bagal"
}
},
{
"new_val": {
"first_name":  "e31db5422cd74040" ,
"id":  "efadedd0-56f2-498f-ad04-5191e2be1244" ,
"last_name":  "27d6b3a140235275"
}
},
{
"new_val": {
"first_name":  "2ba4a9d0e3616865" ,
"id":  "f5c7f3b7-23d2-4661-a5b7-91b977635556" ,
"last_name":  "b7f4df90a27bb05b"
}
},
{
"state":  "initializing"
}
```

And with skip:

```
r.db('bustest').table('client').orderBy({index: r.desc("id")}).limit(3).changes({squash: 0.05, includeInitial: true, includeStates: true}).skip(3)
```

return:

```
{
"state":  "ready"
},
{
"new_val": {
"first_name":  "Gruzin" ,
"id":  "e9580339-b908-4349-a208-c3d1e25bf7ba" ,
"last_name":  "Bagal"
}
}
```

Skip after changes() didn't work. But pagination with changes() is very important part for my projects.

Answer (score 1):

That's what is documented on https://rethinkdb.com/docs/changefeeds/ruby/#filtering-and-aggregation

You cannot use them with `slice` `skip`. Only `orderBy`, and follow by `limit`. Only `orderBy` before `changes` also works

To paginate the `changes` itself, (mean data return by change feed), after `changes()`, you can call `skip`, and just iterator the return cursor yourself. However, if you use `limit` or `slice` after `changes`, the changefeeds only return that amount of change, and close changefeed.